# Criar tab usando imagens no botão

Tags: wordpress, aba

Preciso criar um bloco TAB para o meu site em wordpress, existem vários plugins que ajudam nisso, mas não descobrir nenhum que eu possa usar imagens no botão. Geralmente são icones, mas meu cliente criou algumas imagens, isso complicou e muito. Além disso, tem a setinha que aparece abaixo do botão, quando está ativo.

Segue a imagem de como deve ficar o TAB:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já instalei vários plugins, mas não consegui fazer com a imagem e nem a seta.
Repare que o botão ativo é amarelo com texto em preto, e os outros inativos são vermelho com texto em branco e a imagem em amarelo.

Preciso muito arrumar esse bloco!

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode resolver isso personalizando um CSS.
Basicamente você tem as imagens de cada tab, transforme essas imagens em icones, e vincula ao id de cada tab.

Para resolver a questão da tab ativa:
Inspeciona o elemento de quando tem alguma tab aberta, provavelmente terá uma class nessa tab (".active" ou algo assim), é só personalizar o css para essa class, deixando o background amarelo e o color preto.
Segue um exemplo rapido...

https://jsfiddle.net/Darlei_Zillmer/nguxshu8/